# jQuery ReferenceError for "define" in jquery.js and for $

Tags: jquery

just started the jQuery tutorial and stuck on the ready event part. Opening the html and file and clicking the "jQuery" link, no alert pop-up comes up like it's supposed to, it goes straight to the jQuery home page instead.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
                alert( "Thanks for checking" );
            });
        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update and more details:**
after checking with Firebug, the two errors are `ReferenceError: define is not defined`for the `jquery.js` file and the `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` for the html file. I'm guessing the latter is due to jQuery not working. I installed jQuery with Bower and copied the jquery.js file in the `src` directory to the same directory as where my html file is. Is this not how it's done? I have tried using the path to this file's original location, but the errors are the same.

**Update 2:** inserting `javascript/jquery` instead of `jquery.js` into the `<script src =` has helped to get rid of the first ReferenceError, `$ is not defined` still comes up.

**The Solution:** using the minimized version of `jquery.js` (i.e. the `jquery.min.js`) got rid of the errors for me. Using the google hosted one `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js` or downloading it to your HD both work.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/h1a9bq7g/. Maybe jQuery isn't loaded and thus your code can't execute. Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provide more useful context information (and help yourself).

Comment: I don't really know how bower works, but since you said you read the jQuery tutorial, just follow the tutorial, it tells you what to do. https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR;** We neeed to reference the *correct* jQuery file either through relative or absolute (either a URI or directory) path.

**Complete Details**:

I was working on a simple website having only one web page `test.html` when I faced the same error in this question:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
> at jquery.js:1

I use Visual Studio code. I had to reference jQuery. So instead of downloading its JS file (to be referenced in `test.html`) from jQuery's official website, I went into command shell of Visual Studio Code and installed jQuery module using below node package manager(npm) command:

```
npm install jquery
```

After the command finishes executing, you will observe a new directory named `node_modules` having `dist`, `external`, `src` as sub-directories:

[image]

Then, I browsed `src` directory and found `jquery.js` file inside it. I thought I can refer jquery in my web page by giving hard-coded path of this file as shown below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="C:\Users\rasik\Desktop\learnJs\node_modules\jquery\src\jquery.js" />
```

Now when I loaded the HTML page, I encountered the error that OP has mentioned.

The issue here is that the jQuery file which needs to be referenced for using jQuery library (when you have installed it through npm) is found under `dist` (short for distributable) directory. I had referenced it from `src` directory. So the issue got resolved when I changed the path as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="C:\Users\rasik\Desktop\learnJs\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js" />
```

`src` folder contains the full source code of jQuery where it references many other files also. Since the other dependency JS files meant for `jquery.js` were not referenced in the `test.html` page, so it was failing to recognize the code which had a dependency on other JS files.

Comment: This solved it for me as well! I was expecting jquery.js to be referenced from the src directory but it was inside dist, found through node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js if installed with npm

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your js script is in another hierarchy? i.e `/javascript/jquery.js`

```
<script src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: though I put this into <script> `if (window.jQuery) {alert("jq working fine");} else {alert("jq not working =/");};` and got the else

Comment: actually, I'm sorry, putting in `"javascript/jquery.js"`, though it is not what the instructions in the official jQuery tutorial say, does get rid of the first error. I'm upvoting this. `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` still comes up, however.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery code to be like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert( "Thanks for checking" );
  });
});
```

The `event.preventDefault()` part will prevent the clicked element from performing its default behavior, which in the case of an `a` element is to go the the page defined in its `href` attribute.

Comment: yeah, it says to do that in the next step, but it doesn't help. I still get `ReferenceError: define is not defined` for the `jquery.js` file and the `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` for the html file